# Xamarin.Android Native App works in simulator, works when deployed to device, but then the "published" apk does not work

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play

I have created app using xamarin android native. When I test in simulator from visual studio, then it works fine.

Then I connect with real device and test from visual studio, then also it works

Now I follow all steps to generate APK file, archive and all and get APK file.

Now I upload it to google play and it also approved.

But when I download that same app from google play store, then it does not work in my device.

When I install it and open then give me following error.

Sorry Your App Has Stopped.

So can any one tell me how to get solved this and also how can I check what is error for this.

Looking for help..

Thanks all.

*** I get what error is coming, so can any one help me to get solved that.

Error is here :

1>Proguard configuration file 'obj\Release\XbdMerge\proguard\dc663e480.txt' was not found.
1>Proguard configuration file 'obj\Release\XbdMerge\proguard\e843ef2a0.txt' was not found.
1>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java.exe -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\proguard\lib\proguard.jar" -include "'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt'" -include "'obj\Release\proguard\proguard_xamarin.cfg'" -include "'obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_references.cfg'" -include "'obj\Release\proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg'" -include INF/MANIFEST.MF);'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.1\mono.android.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\1\jl\arch-core-common.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\10\jl\bin\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\11\jl\bin\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\12\jl\bin\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\13\jl\bin\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\14\jl\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\15\jl\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\16\jl\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\17\jl\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\18\jl\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\19\jl\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\2\jl\arch-lifecycle-common.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\3\jl\bin\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\4\jl\bin\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\6\jl\bin\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\7\jl\bin\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\8\jl\bin\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF);'obj\Release\lp\9\jl\bin\classes.jar'(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)" -libraryjars "'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar';'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk/platforms/android-27/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar'" -outjars obj\Release\proguard__proguard_output__.jar -optimizations !code/allocation/variable 
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm$zza: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm$zzb: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm$zzc: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm$zzc: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm$zzc: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm$zzc: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm$zzd: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexm$zzd: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexn: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>com.google.android.gms.internal.zzexn: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
1>there were 18 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
1>"java.exe" exited with code 1.

Comment: Review the `logcat` output from the device

Comment: when you deploy from VS, are you using the same profile & settings as you do when you create the APK for the app store?

Comment: @SushiHangover - can you please explain how I can see logcat in device..Thanks

Comment: Yes, I am using that same.

Comment: You need to add logcat from the device where it is failing for us to help you.

Comment: @NickFortescue I have added error in question, it is regarding proguard...can you please get idea from this if possible.

Comment: That error is not from the logcat from the device - it is from the BUILD process. You need to give the logcat error from the device. See https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html